# Woocommerce VAT

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to make VAT applicable only if customer wants it. At the checkout, customer shall chose countries (EU) and based on choice VAT will be applied. However I have struggle with placing option with 0 VAT%. Here is example: https://www.gamivo.com/cart of what I am trying to achieve.

What I have tried so far is to setup list of countries that I am selling to, applied taxes and renamed them all in drop-down to "Country | VAT % amount". 
I used this function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'rename_austria' );

function rename_austria( $countries ) {
   $countries['AT'] = 'Austria | 20% VAT';
   return $countries;
}
```

Then I added custom country and called it "Outside EU | No VAT" - and applied 0 tax for that with following function:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries',  'Outside_EU' );
function Outside_EU( $countries ) {
  $new_countries = array(
                        'OE'  => __( 'Outside EU | Without VAT', 'woocommerce' ),
                        );

    return array_merge( $countries, $new_countries );
}
```

However I am having struggle with placing it on top of the countries list during the checkout and making it always first choice by default.

Comment: Please show what you try, and what is the problem

Comment: @VaheGalstyan I edited my post. Please check it again :)